# Text area in MVC 5

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and MVC 5. my view has in it this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10">
      @Html.LabelFor(m => m.GeneralInfo, new { @class = "col-md-4 col-lg-4 vert-middle" })
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
          @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.GeneralInfo, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 5, @cols = 220 })
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

whatever I do, I can't get the field to increase it's width. I took the code that is generated from view-source-code and put it in simple html file and there the size is very wide. 
I have not made changes to the bootstrap code. I am using 3.3.4.

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: The btoostrap3 form-control CSS class sets the textarea's width to 100% automatically. It is as wide as the parent container by default.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to explicitely set the width inside the predefined bootstrap grid attribute. which not possible and doesn't make sense.

You need to spend a little bit of time to understand Bootstrap grid system , here's a [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) it will save a lot of time in the future and it's crucial if you want to use BS.

back to your code, if your TextArea is already inside the grid system and you want to get it max width of the screen responsively , you should use something like:

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
          @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.GeneralInfo, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 5 })
      </div>
```

Assuming that it's not inside another div.

**12** is the magical number follow that link for more info.

Comment: I wish it was that simple. I know a bit about the bootstrap grid and that is not the answer. I was able to isolate the problem. It is bootstrap that does it. If I remove all references to bootstrap and create a simple form with textarea I have no problems controlling the width. So I upgrade bootstrap using NuGet: Install-Package Bootstrap.MVC

Comment: That did not help either. I have to specifically create style for textarea that overrides bootstrap and specify min-width: 700px for example and only then the width increases. Any ideas?